# Would this theorem also work for any integer $n$, not necessarily a prime ?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Would this theorem also work for any integer $n$, not necessarily a prime ?

[image]

I don't see why it should not, can you verify it or do you have an counterexample for a nonprime integer ?

Comment: Check if the proof uses the primality of $\,p.\,$ Beware that the argument is not complete, e.g. it does not *explicitly* prove that the factorization $\,\bar g \bar h\,$ remains nontrivial, i.e. that $\,\bar g,\bar h\,$ are nonzero nonunits, which is necessary in order to derive the claimed contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

In short, it depends on the notion of irreducibility.

In a commutative rings that are not domains, there are problems with divisibility - or, the situation is simply a bit more complicated: one gets several different notions of associated elements, thus, several notions of irreducible elements, etc.

Just to demonstrate: In this case what can go wrong is that in general $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$, it is no longer true that $fg=h$ implies $\deg f, \deg g \leq \deg h$. For example, over $\mathbb{Z}_8[x],$ one has
$$(4x^2+4x+2)(4x^{100}+4x+2)=4.$$

Thus, from the fact that $\bar{f}(x)$ has bigger degree than, say $\bar g(x)$, it does not simply follow that $\bar{f}(x)$ does not divide $\bar g(x)$.

So one must treat this more carefully. I am, however, convinced, that if done right, the statement will hold even for general $n$. (I can give more details if anyone wishes.)

Comment: but if $\bar f(x)$ is monic then the theorem applies ?

Comment: Yes, that is one solution (monic polynomial cannot divide polynomials of lesser degree in any polynomial ring). The other is to define irreducible element $r$ to be an element such that whenever $r=ab$, then there is a _unit_ $u$ such that either $r=au,$ or $r=bu$.